# Returning a value from python script while runnig this python script via c execlp function?

Tags: python, c, exec

I am trying to run a python file via execlp function of c language. I want to return a string from the python script. Is there any way to do that?

```
execlp("python", "python", "sendmail.py", "test", (char*) NULL);
```

Comment: No process can *return* a string, but it is possible for one process to convey multi-character data to another via a wide variety of I/O mechanisms.  You're probably looking for redirection of the child process's standard output (or standard error) to a pipe, from which the parent can read it.  You will find numerous questions here on SO about setting up such an arrangement.

Comment: I understand your comment, thanks for the help.

Comment: Just use `popen("python sendmail.py test", "r")` instead. You can of course do your own `pipe`, `fork`, `execlp` + `wait` thing, but why bother? Notice that `execlp` will REPLACE your program with the python, in the same process, so the python cannot possibly _return_ anything.